# can't rename all files in a folder

Tags: java, android

I have some pictures in a folder on sdcard with these names:

```
000.jpg
001.jpg
002.jpg
003.jpg
004.jpg
...
```

the sort of names is so important and should always be like this. Now I want to keep this sort even after deleting a photo. I mean if I deleted for example the third photo, then my fourth photo should be renamed to 002, fifth to 003 and so on.

I writed this code for my purpose:

```
// "myfiles" is a File array of directory listfiles.
// "str1" is my folder name and I checked it for existences before
// "numb" is the pic number that should delete.
File pic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Albummaker/" + str1 + "/" + String.format("%03d", numb) + ".jpg");
pic.delete();
// now I get the myfiles (I mean after deleting).
for (int i = numb; i < myfiles.length; i++) {
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Albummaker/" + str1 + "/"+myfiles[i].getName());
        f.renameTo(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Albummaker/" + str1 + "/"+String.format("%03d", i)+".jpg"));
    }
```

but when I run this it deletes the photos before the deleted one (In this case 001 and 002) and then rename rest of them (and I'll have 3 photos after this (002, 003, 004)).

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file and restore the ordering afterwards. Rename them numbering from 1 upwards.

This is the pseudo-code:

```
// first get rid of the file
albumFile.delete();

// then restore the ordering in the album
organizeALbum(albumDir);

void organizeAlbum(albumDir) {
    var files = albumDir.getFiles("*.jpg");
    var sortedFiles = files.sort(); // sort ascending from 000.jpg to 999.jpg
    int index = 1;
    foreach (file in files) {
        file.rename(index.toString("###") + ".jpg");
        index += 1;
    }
}
```

This is pseudo-code, but you can figure it out in Android java.